# Customize UIImageView size for each device with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, autolayout, size-classes

I'm only starting to learn Auto Layout and i've hit a wall.

In my Attributes Inspector under PREVIEW, i'm using my main storyboard to preview for every iOS device. I'm learning to use auto layout so I can now move an image/label... anywhere on screen I want it to be on all devices.

However, lets say my UIImageview is 25pixels width by 35 pixels height. I want to keep that UIImageview size for iPhone 6. However, for iPhone 4s, I want that UIImageview to be 15 Pixels Width by 25 Pixels height and for iPad PRO 50 pixels width by 70 pixels height.

If i'm using a single storyboard and 1 UIImageView, how do I change the standard 25x35 UIImageview pixel to customize its size for every device the size I want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Even using size-classes, customizing a single view for every target device is too specific for storyboards with size-classes to be doing such a thing.  In general, what you can do is make your UIImageView a specific width and height for iPhones and then a different width and height for iPads.  I believe the size class for iPhones in portrait is compact width and regular height while the size class for iPad is regular height and regular width.

You can be specific enough to target 3.5, 4, and 4.7 inch iPhones in landscape with the compact width/compact height combination, but all iPhones in portrait are compact width/regular height

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html